# Is (https://api.instagram.com/v1/users//media/recent/?access_token=) deprecated?

Tags: php, typo3, instagram-api

I am working with instagram API, i want my all media including photos and reel of instagram
on my website.
I developed my own site in typo3 version 11.
When i enter this url of API it's show's bad request like below.

```
PHP Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.instagram.com/v1/users//media/recent/?access_token=): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in controller
```

Can anyone help me to get my instagram media to my site?
Many Thanks.

Comment: Before implementing the API in your TYPO3 extension I'd advise to test it with simple script(s). For me it looks like the problem is related to basic problems with the API and it's fundamental to understand how to create the links.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have cleared fundamental now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`api.instagram.com` should only be used to get user access token for Instagram. In order to get user's media, you'll need to use `graph.instagram.com` - see the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview).